# Filtering and manipulating "None" or "Null" rows in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, null

So I am trying to assign a new value to a row within a column if that row is empty. I have tried to check if there is a null row, then write in a manipulation statement but it does not seem to be working. For example, if column A is equal to "Big", column B being "None", then I would want that row in column B to be equal to "Tall". If column B already has a value, then it is fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Sample dataframe:

```
Column A    Column B
   Big         None
   Big         Tall
   Small       Short
   Medium      None
   Small       None
   Medium      Average
```

Code I have tried:

```
df.loc[df['Column B'].isnull(), 'Column B'] = 'Fill' #used to fill in the "None Type" rows?
df['Column A'] = df['Column A'].astype(str)
for row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[df['Column B'].str.contains('Fill'):
       df.loc[df['Column A'].str.contains('Big'), 'Column B'] = 'Tall'
       df.loc[df['Column A'].str.contains('Medium'), 'Column B'] = 'Average'
       df.loc[df['Column A'].str.contains('Small'), 'Column B'] = 'Short'
```

However, this fails out. Just trying to replace the "None" Column B values with the respective values above that are determined from the Column A values.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the trick

```
map = {'Big':'Tall','Medium':'Average','Small':'Short',}

def fill(data):
    if data['Column B'] is None  :
        data['Column B'] = map[data['Column A']]
    return data

df.apply(fill,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of the replacements you need, you can use [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to create a column of values you'd like to use as defaults. You can then use [`pd.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill in the NaN values, with the alignment of the missing data and the preferred backup happening automatically because they both have the same index.

In your case:

```py
replacements = {
    'Big': 'Tall',
    'Medium': 'Average',
    'Small': 'Short',
}

backups = df['Column A'].replace(replacements)
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].fillna(backups)
```

For this to work, you'll need to make sure that all of your missing values in column B are coded as `<NA>` (or NaN prior to pandas 1.0.0) *before attempting the fillna operation*.

In pandas >= 1.0.0:

```py
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].astype('string')
```

In versions of pandas prior to 1.0.0:

```py
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].replace({'None': np.nan, None: np.nan})
```

For more info see the docs on [Working with Text Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text-data-types) ([same section, pandas <= 1.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/user_guide/text.html))